# What is the symbol to denote that two triangles are similar?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, notation, relations, triangles

Does there exist a unique symbol to denote that two triangles are similar to each other without resorting to using the phrase "is similar"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DEF$.

Answer (score 6):

The symbol for denoting similar triangles is ($\color{blue}{\sim}$)

Notice, suppose $\triangle ABC$ & $\triangle PQR$ are similar then in LaTex it is written as **$\text{"\triangle ABC \sim \triangle PQR"}$** surrounded in-between by 2 or 4 dollar signs  which appears as follows $$\color{blue}{\triangle ABC \sim \triangle PQR}$$